How to stop decrement by using function and useState in react JS
I created a card in reactJS for ecommerce app. Add to cart button and increment or decrement button also work here in same card. when I click increment button, they perform work accurately and increment number one by one. When I click decrement button, they could not perform task. I want, when I click decrement button, number decrements and stops on zero no negative value shown me.
const [cart, setCart] = useState({});
const handleDeleteToCart = (item) => {
    if (cart.item > 0) {
      setCart((pre) => ({ ...pre, [item.id]: (pre[item.id] || 0) - 1 }));
    }
  };


What is cart.item in your code? I appears to be undefined unless you are explicitly setting is elsewhere. Please [edit] to include a complete and accurate [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

Try the below it will work
const handleDeleteToCart = (itemId) => {
  setCart((prevCart) => {
    const currentQuantity = prevCart[itemId] || 0;
    if (currentQuantity > 0) {
      return {...prevCart, [itemId]: currentQuantity - 1 };
    }
    return prevCart; // Return the original cart if the quantity is already 0
  });
};


"Try this" is not answer. Please explain how this snippet actually solves the issue
